# Turning off the html interpretation in php

Tags: php, html, tags

I have a problem with getting some html value stored in a php array:

```
$data = array("Name"=>'<div style="color:red"></div>');
while(list($key,$val) = each($data)){
  print_r($key." => ".$val) ;
}
```

The problem is that the script (put inside html tags) returns:

```
Name =>
Foo Bar
```

So, the div (so the html) is interpretated.
What I want to display is the value, not its interpretation. So, the result that I want is:

```
Name => <div style="color:red">Foo Bar</div>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much,

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display the actual HTML as stored in your array, then you need to convert the special characters into HTML entities using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), or `htmlspecialchars()`. ie. you need to convert `<` into `&lt;` to display the character correctly on the page.

```
print_r($key." => ".htmlentities($val)) ;
```

`htmlentities()` converts all characters that have HTML entity equivalents. `htmlspecialchars()` converts just the essentials.

Answer (score 4):

This is the browser interpreting the HTML, not PHP. Simply send the page with a content type of `text/plain` and the browser will not try to interpret it.

Comment: Yes but it will display the html source code ... is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: @Zakarai — What do you want it to do? Parse the HTML and then strip out anything that isn't a text node?!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `htmlspecialchars` your output, so the HTML tags get replaced by entities.